# Custom Classes not being retained

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I have a NSXMLParser that parses YT's API. It then turns all the videos into a class I wrote called video. Then the class is put into an array. Then back at my rootviewcontroller I access xmlParser.allVideos (xmlParser is a class I wrote that is the delegate for the xml parser.
Here is what I do with it in the viewDidLoad:

```
arrayFromXML = xmlParser.allVideos;
```

Then in the drawing of the tableView I do this:

```
tempVideo = [arrayFromXML objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = tempVideo.videoTitle; //crashes here and says NSString has been deallocated.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `arrayFromXML` is an instance variable you have to `retain` or `copy` (to be safe from later manipulation) the array as `xmlParser` simply might not be alive anymore when other methods are called later:

```
arrayFromXML = [xmlParser.allVideos copy];
```

Or better yet using a `copy` or `retain` property:

```
self.arrayFromXML = xmlParser.allVideos;
```